# For doing a fresh installation of Windows 10, what's the difference between using Windows Setup and Dism /Apply-Image?

Tags: windows-10, dism

I'm trying to do a fresh installation of Windows 10 on a PC with no network connection. The problem is, Microsoft decided to remove the time zone option from OOBE since Windows 10 (WHY?) and I don't live in PST - which is what the en-us version of the official Windows 10 image defaults to. This would make some files have the wrong dates since Windows considers the hardware clock in local time, but my hardware clock isn't in PST.

The simple workaround would be to change the time in the BIOS to PST prior to installing Windows 10 and set the time zone manually post-install. However, I had some free time, so I decided to play around with it and found that I can set the time zone for offline images using `Dism /Set-TimeZone`.

So I went ahead and modified the time zone of the mounted `install.wim` and committed the changes, but to my surprise, after installing Windows 10 using this modified version of install.wim I still get PST as the default time zone. After some trials and errors, I found that if I don't use the Windows Setup but manually apply the modified install.wim using `Dism /Apply-Image`, my time zone setting does work after installation.

Hence, the question: **When doing a fresh installation of Windows 10, what's the difference between using the Windows Setup and `Dism /Apply-Image`?** Why doesn't my time zone setting work when using Windows Setup (it resets back to PST)?